Powershell List full path and filename + date last modified of all files in folder and subfolders, without listing the folders and subfolders itself
With Powershell I want to list the full path and filename + date last modified of all files in the current folder and its subfolders, without listing the folders and subfolders itself.
I managed to come a long way, but how do I surpress the folders and subfolders in the result? I only want info from files, not folders.
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime |
Export-Csv -Path x:\filedetails2.csv -NoTypeInformation


To get only the files, you can use the -File parameter in Get-ChildItem
To get only the File name and full path + the date of last modification, you can pipe the results to Select-Object using the -Property parameter to select only the properties you want to keep before piping to Export-Csv
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\' -Recurse -File | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'x:\filedetails2.csv'  -NoTypeInformation


Btw, -Path . is redundant and Get-ChildItem will default to the current working directory anyways.

yeah, but I always prefer to write down all the parameters and their names in scripts, for maximum readibility

Thank you sirtao! -File was exactly what I needed.
